# how to create this table in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design

i fond it hard to create a table for this problem. can somebody help me?

You are the owner of some tables for Sweeney Tours that have been created for you already. They are:

```
COUNTRY(country, language, timezone, currency)
REGION(region, landtype, country, scenery, page) 
RESORT(resort, region, transfertime, beach, beachnum, page)
HOTELS(hotelid, hotelname, sunbeam, ya, rating, stdbasis, page, resort,       
      resortloc, roomtotal) 
FACILITIES(facid, description, category)
FACINRESORT(resort, facid)
FACINHOTEL(hotelid, facid, numof)
```

Each hotel has one standard meal basis on offer (stdbasis), always one of Half Board (hb), Bed&Breakfast (bb), Full Board (fb) or Apartment Only (ao). Some hotels are designated "Young and Active" (meaning ideal for 18-30 year olds) (ya). A few resorts cater particularly well for children by running a 'SunBeam Club' (sunbeam) where parents can leave their children. These clubs are associated with particular hotels in the resort. Each hotel has a distance from the centre of the resort included (resortloc). The transfer time from the airport to the resort is included (transfertime).

Resort and/or Hotels have facilities such as swimming pools, discos, horse riding, waiter service, kids playgrounds, telephones in bedrooms etc. Facilities fall into a number of different categories:

(6?)

```
accommodation a 
entertainment e 
sport s 
meals m 
children c 
bedroom b
```

Comment: Try to analyze everything, look some tutorials if you are not make sure what should you do to be.

Comment: i tried but i really find it hard. where can i see the tutorials like that ? :(

Comment: Some thing could help you. [HERE](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-create-table.htm).

Comment: What is your background / situation? Are you studying / beginning programming / playing just for fun?

Comment: im studying and im a beginner, we only discussed basic sql commands, so its hard for me to create a table such like that

Comment: and then, how to create a table with primary key on another table ? then how toput in stdbasis 'hb' , 'bb' , 'fb', such like that in the question

Comment: And have you studied any relational modeling / databases? Without it I don't think you have much luck, I am afraid...

Comment: can you help me ? just guide

Comment: Let's try to move this discussion to a chat (if I only knew how to!)

Comment: where can we chat ? facebook ? kik ? where please

Comment: I think if we keep exchanging comments we will be offered automatically to move to a chat

Comment: ive done already creating a COUNTRY table. next is REGION. how can i call the primary key of the COUNTRYtable which is country to be put on the REGIONtable ?

Comment: Create first the REGION table, and show me the script

Comment: 'create table REGION ( region nvarchar(20) primary key,
landtype nvarchar(25) not null , country nvarchar(20) not null, 
scenery nvarchar(25) not null, page int)
go ' @GiorgosAltanis

Comment: ok, now you want HOTEL to have a foreign key to REGION. But what is the HOTEL's primary key?

Comment: I am not sure about this, but I think that RESORT has a FK to REGION and HOTEL has a FK to RESORT (i.e. a `region` has many `resorts`, and a `resort` has many `hotels`)

Comment: Meanwhile, Rahul Gupta has provided a good starting point for you, so I suggest you study and adapt this answer to fit your exact requirements. Take care!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

may be this will help you:

```
CREATE TABLE COUNTRY(
    country VARCHAR(255) PRIMARY KEY,
    language VARCHAR(255),
    timezone TIMESTAMP,
    currency FLOAT
)

CREATE TABLE REGION(
    region VARCHAR(255) PRIMARY KEY,
    landtype VARCHAR(255),
    country VARCHAR(255) FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES COUNTRY(country),
    scenery VARCHAR(255),
    page INTEGER UNIQUE, 
)

CREATE TABLE RESORT(
    resort VARCHAR(255) PRIMARY KEY,
    region VARCHAR(255) FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES REGION(region),
    transfertime TIMESTAMP,
    beach VARCHAR(255),
    beachnum VARCHAR(255),
    page INTEGER FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES REGION(page)
)

CREATE TABLE STDBASIS(
    id INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    code VARCHAR(3),
    description VARCHAR(255) 
)

CREATE TABLE HOTELS(
    hotelid BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    hotelname VARCHAR(255),
    sunbeam VARCHAR(255),
    ya VARCHAR(255),
    rating VARCHAR(255),
    stdbasis VARCHAR(255) FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES STDBASIS(id),
    page INTEGER FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES REGION(page), 
    resort VARCHAR(255) FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES REGION(resort),
    resortloc VARCHAR(255),
    roomtotal INTEGER,
    CONSTRAINT chk_stdbasis CHECK (stdbasis BETWEEN 0 AND 4)
)

CREATE TABLE FACILITIES(
    facid VARCHAR(255) PRIMARY KEY,
    description VARCHAR(255),
    category INTEGER
)

CREATE TABLE FACINRESORT(
    resort VARCHAR(255) FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES REGION(resort),
    facid VARCHAR(255) FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES FACILITIES(facid),
    CONSTRAINT pk_rID PRIMARY KEY (resort,facid)
)

CREATE TABLE FACINHOTEL(
    hotelid VARCHAR(255) FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES HOTELS(hotelid),
    facid VARCHAR(255) FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES FACILITIES(facid),
    numof INTEGER,
    CONSTRAINT pk_hID PRIMARY KEY (hotelid,facid)
)
```

Please change datatypes and primary/foreign keys as per your business problem

you need to insert data in STDBASIS table as below:

```
INSERT INTO STDBASIS
(code, description) 
VALUES 
("hb", "Half Board"),
("bb", "Bed&Breakfast"),
("fb", "Full Board"),
("ao", "Apartment Only")
```

you need to insert data in FACILITIES table as below:

```
INSERT INTO FACILITIES
(facid , description) 
VALUES 
("a", "accommodation"),
("e", "entertainment"),
("s", "sport"),
("m", "meals"),
("c", "children"),
("b", "bedroom")
```

Comment: thanks a lot. last question. how will i put in the stdbasis the Half Board (hb), Bed&Breakfast (bb), Full Board (fb) or Apartment Only (ao) ?    and facilities with these accommodation a 
entertainment e 
sport s 
meals m 
children c 
bedroom b

Comment: you have to create a saperate table for stdbasis which is like this:

     stdbasis(id, description)

and use this in as a foreign key in hotel table and set a contraint over foriegn key to range between 0 to 4.

Comment: check the updated solution, may be this will help you and understand the sql

Comment: i will create table stdbasis? where will i put the hb, bb, fb, ao ?

and the Resort and/or Hotels have facilities such as swimming pools, discos, horse riding, waiter service, kids playgrounds, telephones in bedrooms etc. Facilities fall into a number of different categories:

accommodation a 
entertainment e 
sport s 
meals m 
children c 
bedroom b

Comment: your stdbasis table contains the 4 enties:
    id description
    1 hb
    2 bb
    3 fb
    4 ao

Comment: your facilities are come in facility table like: facid description
a acommodation
e entertainment
s sports
m meals
...

Comment: CREATE TABLE STDBASIS(
    id INTEGER identity(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    description VARCHAR(255) , 1 hb , 2 bb , 3 fb , 4 ao
)

Comment: check the updated solution, may be it will help you to analyze the solution better and help you to think about the business problem as well